# How do I fix the problem about name-password correspondence?

Tags: java

I am new at programming. I want to make a program that checks the input name and password are same or not, if it is, the program must say "Your name and your password cannot be same".My code is like below but even both of two input are same or different, result is same. What am i doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project {
public static void main(String[]args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name ");
String name =scan.nextLine();       
System.out.println("Please Enter Yout Password for register");
String password=scan.nextLine();

if(name.equals(password.startsWith(password))) {        

    System.out.println("Your name and your password cannot be same");}
else {
    System.out.println("Register is successful");
}
}
}
```

Comment: `name.equals(password.startsWith(password))` should be `name.equals(password)` For more informations red the javadoc!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
if(name.equals(password.startsWith(password))) {
```

To:

```
if (name.equals(password)) {
```

#### Why it fails

It seems that you inadvertently added `.startsWith(password)` into the condition.

#### Explanation about what's happening

The expression `password.startsWith(password)` returns the `boolean` value `true`. Which causes the condition for the if statement to be: `if(name.equals(true))` which always returns `false` because a `String` never `equals()` a `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!